# useQuery always returning undefined data in react-query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, axios, react-query

I'm new to react-query and I'm trying to move all of my API calls into a new file, out of the useQuery calls.
Unfortunately when I do this all of my data is undefined.

**I do see the network calls in the network tab, it just isn't being set properly in useQuery.**

Thanks in advance for any help on how to change my code to fix this!

```js
   // this works
    const { loading, data, error } = useQuery([conf_id], async () => {
       const { data } = await axios.get(API_URL + '/event/' + conf_id)
       return data
    });
```

```js
    // this doesn't work - data is undefined
    const axios = require('axios');
    
    const getEventById = async () => {
      const { data } = await axios.get(API_URL + '/event/2541' + '?noyear=true');
      return data.data;
    };
    
    const { loading, data, error } = useQuery('conf_id', getEventById});
    // the below variants don't work either
    // const { loading, data, error } = useQuery('conf_id', getEventById()});
    // const { loading, data, error } = useQuery('conf_id', async () => await getEventById()});
   // const { loading, data, error } = useQuery('conf_id', async () => await 
   //    const { data } = getEventById(); return data
   // });
```

Comment: What is the shape of the API response?

Comment: It is an object. Looks like this
{name: string, date: date, champion: array, deadlines: array}

Comment: So the object doesn't have a data property? Then why are you trying to return the data property from it in `getEventById`. I think you just need to `return data`. Then your useQuery would look like: `const { isLoading, data, error } = useQuery('conf_id', getEventById});` And you can access those values via `data.name` or `data.deadlines`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

An [AxiosResponse](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/1f13dd7e26124a27c373c83eff0a8614acc1a04f/index.d.ts#L133) has a `data` attribute from which you can access the actual API JSON response.

Like you pointed out, this:

```js
async () => {
       const { data } = await axios.get(API_URL + '/event/' + conf_id)
       return data
    }
```

Should suffice for the fetching function.

So the final implementation should look like

```js
    const axios = require('axios');
    
    const getEventById = async () => {
      const { data } = await axios.get(API_URL + '/event/2541' + '?noyear=true');
      return data;
    };
    
    const { loading, data, error } = useQuery('conf_id', getEventById);
```

The `data` you get from the `useQuery` should be undefined on the first render and once the server responds it will change to whatever the response is.